# C# System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays

Im having some problems trying to resolve this C# error:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at DayZMap.ProcessMemory.CutString(String mystring) in Z:\p\Memory.cs:line 45
   at DayZMap.Map.refreshMap(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e) in Z:\p\Form1.cs:line 517
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPrint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPrintClient(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The function it is crashing on is:

```
public string CutString(string mystring)
{
    char[] chArray = mystring.ToCharArray();
    string str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < mystring.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((chArray[i] == ' ') && (chArray[i + 1] == ' '))
        {
            return str;
        }
        if (chArray[i] == '\0')
        {
            return str;
        }
        str = str + chArray[i].ToString();
    }
    return mystring.TrimEnd(new char[] { '0' });
}
```

It throws the exception on the line:

```
if ((chArray[i] == ' ') && (chArray[i + 1] == ' '))
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: when i = mystring.Length-1, i+1 = mystring.Length that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that when you are indexing `chArray[i + 1]`, you are exceeding the size of the array.

Take, for example, if `chArray` has 5 characters, when `i` is `4` in your loop, it will attempt to access `chArray[5]` with your code, which is out of bounds (the bounds of the array in that example would be 0-4).

I don't know what you meant for this code to do, but one fix would be to limit your `for` by one less:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mystring.Length - 1; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

`chArray[i + 1]` is outside the length of the array, you likely meant to iterate to `mystring.Length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

On the last iteration of your loop `i` is the largest valid index of that collection.

You try to access the item at index `i + 1`.  That index doesn't exist.

You can loop up to the second-to-last valid index if you need to access the "next" index in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (... && (chArray[i + 1] == ' '))
```

When `i == myString.Length - 1`, that line goes one past the bounds of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If the last character is ' ' you are indexing at an out of bounds positions with `chArray[i + 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing in C# starts from 0, and the Length value of the array counts from 1, so a simple fix would be to change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mystring.Length; i++)
```

for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mystring.Length - 1; i++)
```

There are other platforms like Matlab, that indexes arrays counting from 1, so , in there your code could have success!.
Cheers!!!